# Angular Promises and forEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using angular for a couple of weeks now, just for building personal apps, and try to get the feeling of it, so far so good I think, though I have been having problems with promises lately.

What I want to achieve is the following:
 - Make a call to an api to retrieve a list of countries
 - Once I have that list perform a new call for each country to get an image for that country
 - Then, populate my $scope element with Country, Capital, Region and Image and render the info to the page

My code works fine locally, but when deployed to heroku it doesnt seem to work on google chrome.... for some reason, it does work on any other browser and mobile even on a new Chrome Incognito window... but on a plain chrome browser I get 404 for all the images... is there something wrong in my code?

So far I a not using factories, so all my logic is the controller, I know its not ideal ;)

Thanks a lot for your help!

And [here](https://ar-angular-countries.herokuapp.com/#/) is the live link if you need it

```
angular.module('angularCountriesApp')
  .controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    function getCountries() {
      return $http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all", { cache: true});
    }

    function getImages(country){
      return $http.get("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos/search?term="+  country+"&tag=landscape&image_size=4&rpp=1&consumer_key=XXXX", { cache: true});
    }


    var coutriesPromise = getCountries();

    coutriesPromise.then(function(countries) {
      var countriesList = [];
      // console.log(countries);
      angular.forEach(countries.data, function(country){

        var name    = country.name;
        var capital = country.capital;
        var region  = country.region;

        var imagesPromise = getImages(country.name);

        imagesPromise.then(function(images){


          var image = images.data.photos[0].image_url;
          countriesList.push({
            'name' : name,
            'capital' : capital,
            'region' : region,
            'image' : image
          });

          $scope.countries = countriesList;

        });
      })

    }, function(reason) {
      console.log(reason);
    });

  }]);
```

Comment: are you getting any console errors or XHR errors?

Comment: The live site doesnt help as it accessing images from you local server
https://api.500px.com/v1/photos/search
please share the error details

Comment: works here... even on chrome. what error message do you get?

Comment: Hey folks!, thanks for your answer I replied to this thread not long after I posted it... I thought I resolved it, anyhow it ended up being a Chrome extension I had installed, which was preventing the images from downloading... that's why it worked fine on an incognito window....

But if you dont mind I would appreciate a feedback as far as my logic goes, would there be a better way to achieve the same result? or maybe a more angular way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out... I have a chrome extension that was preventing the images from loading..... nonetheless if you have a better approach for my code, please speak up!